# NPAPI and Google Chrome on Linux

Tags: linux, google-chrome, npapi

I'm working on an NPAPI plugin on Linux and have run into several issues with Google Chrome (albeit it works perfectly on Firefox).

Firstly, the plugin execution would hang and after a long harrowing time I figured out that the call to `NPN_Evaluate` hangs when the last parameter (for the returned `result`) is NULL. It works on Firefox fine. The solution was to pass the address of an `NPVariant` type variable as the parameter and just ignore the value.

After that the plugin loads fine but I'm stuck with this error message:
[8886:8886:195170759489:ERROR:webkit/glue/plugins/webplugin_delegate_impl_gtk.cc(129)] Not implemented reached in bool WebPluginDelegateImpl::WindowedCreatePlugin() windowed plugin but without xembed. See http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=38229

Any ideas on how I could get this plugin working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use XEmbed in your plugin to work with Chrome. Docs here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XEmbed_Extension_for_Mozilla_Plugins

FireBreath uses this method: http://firebreath.org

it is open source (BSD license), so you could either use it with your plugin or you could shamelessly "borrow" the code for xembed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply... Already figured out that XEmbed solves the problem :) ... what I'm doing now is very simple... When the browser queries the plugin to check if it supports XEmbed, I'm returning TRUE. And that solves it!